# Static code analysis integrated with Git/GitHub

Tags: gratis, code-analysis, github, continuous-integration

I have a GitHub project [integrated with Travis](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/getting-started/).

Every time a commit is pushed, Travis tries to compile, and warn if it does not compile.

To take it further, I would like to integrate with a tool for [static code analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_code_analysis):

- Find duplicate code
- Find common probable bugs (recognizes the technology automatically, at least: Android, Java, C#)
- Find package dependency cycles
- Bonus: Run applicable off-the-shelf validation tools, for instance Lint for Android

Requirements:

- Run analysis at every commit or at least on a regular basis
- Free
- Preferably a free (or free for open source projects) online service, installable (on-premise) if nothing else available.
- Ideally, it would only require entering a Git URL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org) suits your needs, We use it exactly the same way you want but with jenkins and for java-based code(supports multiple languages though, no need to worry).
E.g. pushed a commit -> Jenkins builds and deploys -> updates SonarQube which gives online statistics. I imagine setting SonarQube with Travis wouldn't be too much trouble since 
it provides a lot of plugins for that reason.

**UPDATE:** Some plugins and general information for getting started with Jenkins and Sonarqube:

- [Here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin) is the plugin for Jenkins+Github
- [Here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Sonar+plugin) is the plugin for Jenkins+SonarQube
- [Here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Configuring+SonarQube+Jenkins+Plugin) is a link with further information about configuration of
  Jenkins+SonarQube

Comment: So setting up this requires to install Jenkins and SonarQube, the <a href="https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin">integrate Github and Jenkins</a>, then <a href="http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Configuring+SonarQube+Jenkins+Plugin">integrate Jenkins and SonarQube</a>, right?

Comment: Yes Jenkins has this [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Sonar+plugin) for that reason. I haven't setted up myself but found many [resources](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Configuring+SonarQube+Jenkins+Plugin) in a google search to get started. For github Jenkins offers(what a surprise) another [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin).

Comment: @NicolasRaoul If you managed to get it working on Travis CI, then I would be interested to hear so. My main problem is how to publish the information somewhere.

Comment: @skiwi I, too, would like to integrate SonarQube with Travis CI, and still didn't find any solution. I would be ok to move to another CI tool, but I don't want to host or pay for anything, so Travis was nice. Did you find anything in the end?

Comment: @Joffrey No, I haven't looked further into this matter as far as I remember.

Answer (score 1):

For languages compiled by [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (i.e. C++, C, Ada, Fortran, Go, D, ....) you could consider using a specialized [MELT](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt) extension. (you'll probably need to code some MELT, depending on the analysis you want to do).

For C, you might also consider [Frama C](http://frama-c.com/) or Clang

Comment: The main requirement is "integrated with Github". Ideally, it would only require entering a hook address and maybe accepting an OAuth authentication.

Answer (score 1):

[Coverity](https://scan.coverity.com/github) looks like what you want. I am starting to try it now for one of my projects but it seems promising.

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! This post does not contain enough information to be considered a high quality answer. Please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/107) to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer, otherwise it will be removed. Like does it match all or just some of Nicolas's requirements?

Comment: I looked into Coverity, but my main problem is that it [cannot be triggered on pull-requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26759088/run-coverity-scan-for-every-travis-pull-request-build), which is a no-go for me. Also, I didn't find any way of customizing the rules for the scan, but maybe I just didn't dig enough.

Answer (score 1):

I made [Gradle and Maven plugins](https://github.com/tomasbjerre/violation-comments-to-github-lib) for that. It currently supports Findbugs, PMD, Checkstyle, CSSLint and JSHint, but support for more are planned. The result may look something like this:

[image: Pull request in GitHub with static code analysis]

Comment: Nice! Does it satisfy the first requirement "Run analysis at every commit"? Thanks :-)

Comment: For every commit on pull requests, yes.

Comment: There is also Jenkins and Maven plugins available now =) https://github.com/tomasbjerre/violation-comments-to-github-lib